# Why could only a Prime defeat the Fallen?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, revenge-of-the-fallen

In **Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen**, Jetfire reveals that only a Prime could defeat the Fallen.

So why is it that only a Prime could defeat the Fallen?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any canon answer we can give.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of raw offensive power, and defensive invulnerability compared to non-Primes. Only a Prime could withstand or fend off the Fallen's attack or hope to do damage, probably. A toddler with a stick possibly *could* take out a knight with a mace mounted on a huge horse, but practically speaking, not.  Same for a lamb vs a healthy adult male tiger.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The Fallen himself was once a Prime. Optimus is the only Prime left although he is not as strong as his ancestors, and that is why when he came back, he needed Jetfire's parts to defeat The Fallen. There are 2 versions to it: first is that, it's their nature law, that if you are a Prime no one can defeat you unless he(it)'s another Prime. The second one is just a prophecy that The Fallen can be beaten only by a Prime.